# Blazor WASM Client App: How to interact clean with Azure Api

Tags: c#, blazor, webassembly, clean-architecture

I have to develop a little tutorial Blazor application that gets data from an Azure IoT Central Application with the REST API. I want to implement this solution so clean as possible.
The Blazor WASM has to use the HttpClient (as DataService) Object to send queries to the Api. I don't know, which the best solution is? If the HttpClient queries and commands are in the Application layer or in the Blazor App (do in the presentation layer)?

I have no clean implemented code yet, that is why I have this question.
May the force be with you

Comment: It is an opinion based question